# The involution of tensor product

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

**Proposition 3.1.8** (Linear independence). If $\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\}\subset X$ are linearly independent, $\{y_{1},...,y_{n}\}\subset Y$ are arbitrary and 
$$0=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\otimes y_{i}\in X\odot Y,$$
then $y_{1}=y_{2}=...=y_{n}=0.$ (Here, $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary vector spaces and $X\odot Y$ denotes the algebraic tensor product.)

Let $A$ and $B$ be the C*-algebras, the involution on all of $A\odot B$ is defined by 
$$\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}\otimes b_{i}\mapsto \sum\limits_{i}a_{i}^{*}\otimes b_{i}^{*}$$
and to prove that this is well defined, it suffices to show that if $\sum_{i}a_{i}\otimes b_{i}=0$, then $\sum_{i}a_{i}^{*}\otimes b_{i}^{*}=0$ as well. **Expanding the $a_{i}$'s out in terms of a basis for $A$ and playing around with the tensor calculus and linear independence will show this to be true.**

Well, it is a quotation of a book above. **My question is how to expand the $a_{i}$ out in terms of a basis and how to use the linear independence to show the well defined of the map?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a basis $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k\}$ of the subspace $\text{span}\{b_1,b_2,\ldots, b_n\}$ and write
$$
b_i =\sum_j \alpha_{i,j}v_j
$$
If $\sum_i a_i\otimes b_i = 0$, it follows that
$$
\sum_i (\sum_j\alpha_{i,j}a_i)\otimes v_i = 0
$$
Since the $\{v_i\}$ are linearly independent, your lemma proves that
$$
\sum_j \alpha_{i,j}a_i = 0 \quad\forall i\Rightarrow \sum_j \overline{\alpha_{i,j}} a_i^{\ast} = 0
$$
Hence,
$$
\sum_i a_i^{\ast}\otimes b_i^{\ast} = \sum_i (\sum_j \overline{\alpha_{i,j}}a_i^{\ast})\otimes v_i^{\ast} = 0
$$

Comment: Many thanks to you.