# The multiplication of tensor product

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

**Proposition 3.1.15** (Multiplication). Let $A$, $B$ be C*-algebra, the tensor product $A\odot B$ (denotes the algebraic tensor product) has a multiplication defined by 
$$(\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}\otimes b_{i})(\sum\limits_{j}c_{j}\otimes d_{j})=\sum\limits_{i,j}a_{i}c_{j}\otimes b_{i}d_{j}.$$

**To prove that this multiplication works**, we first consider $L(A\odot B)$, the vector space of all linear maps $A\odot B\rightarrow A\odot B$. If $M_{a}: A\rightarrow A$ is left multiplication by $a\in A$ and $M_{b}: B\rightarrow B$ is left multiplication by $b\in B$, then, for every pair $(a, b)\in A \times B$ we have the tensor product map $M_{a}\otimes M_{b}\in L(A\odot B)$. It is routine to check that 
$$A\times B\rightarrow L(A\odot B),~(a, b)\mapsto M_{a}\otimes M_{b}$$
is a bilinear map. By universality there is a linear map $M: A\odot B \rightarrow L(A\odot B )$ such that $M(a\otimes b)=M_{a}\otimes M_{b}$. Finally one checks that the bilinear map
$$A\odot B \times A\odot B \rightarrow A\odot B , (x, y)\mapsto M(x)y$$ 
defines our multiplication.

It is a quotation above. **I do not know what is the meaning of "to prove this multiplication works". Does the author want to show the multiplication $\sum\limits_{i,j}a_{i}c_{j}\otimes b_{i}d_{j}\in A\odot B$?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplication is defined in terms of the individual elements of $\sum_ia_i\otimes b_i$ and $\sum_ic_i\otimes d_i$. This means that you need it to be independent of the choice; that is, if $\sum_ia_i'\otimes b_i'=\sum_ia_i\otimes b_i$ and $\sum_ic_i'\otimes d_i'=\sum_i c_i\otimes d_i$, you need $\sum_ia_i'c_i'\otimes b_i'd_i'=\sum_ia_ic_i\otimes b_i d_i$.

Comment: But, in the proof, where do the author show the multiplication is independent of the choice?

Comment: In the words "by universality". This is a reference to the standard fact that a bilinear map $\alpha$ on $A\times B$ induces a unique linear map $\tilde\alpha$ on $A\otimes B$. The proof goes exactly along the same lines as the previous proof: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783223/the-involution-of-tensor-product

Comment: Oh, yes, I get the point. By the way, do you mean the proof of the universality is along the same lines as the proof: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783223/the-involution-of-tensor-product

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: Oh, Thanks Martin.